Is there a replacement for assumeThat in JUnit 5?
I am migrating code from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. Is there any replacement for the method Assume.assumeThat?

I did not find any equivalent method in JUnit 5  so I created my own implementation of an assumeThat method, basted on the one in JUnit 4. I also added logging to stderr as I wanted it to be more verbose than the Assumptions methods normally are.
package org.example;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.StringDescription;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;

public class Assume {

    public static <T> void assumeThat(String message, T actual, Matcher<T> matcher) {
        if (!matcher.matches(actual)) {
            final StringDescription description = new StringDescription();
            if (message != null) {
                description.appendText(message);
                description.appendText(": ");
            }
            description.appendText("got: ");
            description.appendValue(actual);
            description.appendText(", expected: ");
            description.appendDescriptionOf(matcher);
            final String fullMessage = description.toString();
            System.err.println(fullMessage);
            Assumptions.abort(fullMessage);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void assumeThat(T actual, Matcher<T> matcher) {
        assumeThat(null, actual, matcher);
    }

}

